# Mschart control.columnlabel not retrieving data from Ado using VB6

Tags: winforms, vba, vb6, ado, mschart

I'm new to VB6 and I am having a problem in MSChart.columnlabel where I will be retrieving data from database and this i have name field in my product table. The problem is whenever I run the program a msgbox will popped

"item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." Please help me. Thank you

Ill post my code here:

```
Private cn As ADODB.Connection
Private rsProducts As ADODB.Recordset
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
MSChart1.ToDefaults

Const ConnectionString = "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver; SERVER=10.237.2.152; DATABASE=monitoring;UID=root;PWD=c0k3float;DSN=itemearv;"
' Open the connection.
   cn.Open ConnectionString
   Dim strQuery As String ' SQL query string.

   ' Create a query that retrieves only four fields.
   'strQuery = "SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice,
   'UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder  FROM Products"
   strQuery = "Select value from test.product"
   Set rsProducts = New ADODB.Recordset
   ' Open the recordset.
   rsProducts.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   rsProducts.Open strQuery, cn, adOpenKeyset
   ' Set the DataSource to the recordset.
   With MSChart1
         .ShowLegend = True
       Set .DataSource = rsProducts
       .ColumnCount = rsProducts.RecordCount
       .RowCount = 1
       .RowLabel = "TESTING"
    End With
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    While i <= rsProducts.RecordCount
        With MSChart1
            .Column = i
            .Row = 1
            .Data = rsProducts!Value
            .ColumnLabel = rsProducts!Name
            End With
            rsProducts.MoveNext
            i = i + 1

    Wend
    Set rsProducts = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `select` command to include `Name`:

```
strQuery = "Select value,Name from test.product"
```

Comment: Correct, value field in table test is selected but you made a call to return data on Name field as well resulting in your error as the Name does not exist in returned data.